# When to use Git Clone and Git Pull?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and am struggling with this concept.

Here's my scenario: I have set up a branch on my local. I now want to get the files from a branch(?) on github so I can work on them.

Which do I use and why?

Comment: Files are not "in a branch" so much as they are "in a commit". In fact, in Git, the term *branch* is ambiguous: it can refer to a branch *name* like `master`, or to a chain of commits ending at a commit called the *tip* or *head*. A branch *name* points to a *tip commit*, and that tip-most commit points backwards to a parent commit, which points backwards again to *its* parent, and so on.

Comment: As for when to use `git pull`, my preferred answer is "never", and second-level preference is "only after you've learned that `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`".  So: `git clone` means "make a copy of some repository", while `git fetch` means "in the repository where I am now, go fetch updates—stuff that's new since last copied/fetched". Once you have their (some other Git's) updates safely copied over, you can either `merge` or `rebase` to combine *their* work and *your* work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use clone when you don't have a copy of the repository on your current machine, or if you want to make a new, separate copy.

Use pull when you have a copy of the repository, and you want to pull in changes from some outside source (often, but not always, the place you cloned it from).

> Which do I use and why?

In this case, neither one really applies. You want to *check out* the remote branch. Most likely using `git checkout -t origin/branchname`, which sets up a tracking branch.

Comment: Thanks. What if I have an empty repository? Pull?